# Send action from Js to Python simple action server rosnodejs

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, simpleactionclient

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a python simple action server that i run and works with a python simple action client.

```
actionlib.SimpleActionServer('move_to_beacon_action', proximity.msg.BeaconAction, execute_cb=self.execute_cb, auto_start = False)`
```

now i want to use javascript to send an action to the python simple action server. I'm using rosnodejs but dont know how how to send an action. right now connecting doesn't work either. I tried to look for examples but none worked.

```
rosnodejs.initNode('my_node', { onTheFly: true })
.then(() => {
    const proximity = rosnodejs.require('proximity');
    const goal = new proximity.msg.BeaconGoal({ address: 'Hello' });
    const ac = new rosnodejs.SimpleActionClient({
        nh: rosnodejs.nh,
        type: proximity.msg.BeaconAction,
        actionServer: 'move_to_beacon_action'
    });
    ac.waitForServer()
  .then(() => {
    rosnodejs.log.info('Connected to action server!');
  })
```

This doesnt work however. I get the error:

`[INFO] [1586955599.210] (ros): Connected to master at http://192.168.2.10:11311!`
`[ERROR] [1586955599.239] (ros.rosnodejs): Exception trying to advertise topic move_to_beacon_action/goal`

Does anyone know how to do this? am i doing something wrong? Is this even possible?
I' m a big ROS noob and would love help!
Thanks for your time and reading :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349537/send-action-from-js-to-python-simple-action-server-rosnodejs/) by [kopop8](https://answers.ros.org/users/52035/kopop8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2020-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
  const ac = new rosnodejs.SimpleActionClient({
          nh: rosnodejs.nh,
          // the type puts ActionGoal in the end automatically
          type: 'proximity/Beacon',
          actionServer: '/move_to_beacon_action'
      });
```

So it puts ActionGoal at the end of proxwaimity/Beacon that was my mistake

---

Originally posted by [kopop8](https://answers.ros.org/users/52035/kopop8/) with karma: 65 on 2020-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1